# How to stop from printing empty matrix in java

Tags: java, matrix

While this code works and executes, there's a problem with it. The goal of the code is to move [x] across the matrix. It does but, after completing the first row, it prints a completely blank array. Meaning there is no point where both `i == x` and `j == y`.

Then, after it prints again, it continues where it left off. This means it never finishes circling the array by the prints allotted.

A picture to showcase what I mean:

[image: A picture to showcase what I mean].

How would I solve this? It's happening because, after that `else` property of `moveX` activates, `j == 0` and `y == 1`; at least, that's what I have to assume is causing the blank print.

```
public class MovingX {
 
    private int rowsN;  
    private int columnsM;    
    private int[][] matrixArr = new int[rowsN][columnsM];
    private int x = 0;    
    private int y = 0;
    
    public MovingX(int n, int m) {
       rowsN = n;        
       columnsM = m;       
       matrixArr = new int[n][m];       
    }
    
    public void forLoopGrid() {
        for(int i = 0; i < matrixArr.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < matrixArr.length; j++) {
                if(i == x && j == y) System.out.print("[x] ");   
                else {
                    System.out.print("[ ] ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    public void moveX() {      
         if(x < 4) x++;
         else { 
            x = 0; 
            y++;
         } 
    }
    
    public void runProgram() {
        System.out.println("Program Starting");
        System.out.println("Rows, Columns: " + rowsN + " " + columnsM);
        for(int i = 0; i < (rowsN * columnsM); i++) {
            forLoopGrid();
            moveX();
        }
        System.out.println("Program Ending");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {         
        MovingX xLoop =  new MovingX(4, 4);
        xLoop.runProgram();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function `moveX()` you should change condition inside if-statement. Below correct version:

```
public void moveX(){

    if(x < 3) x++;
    else{
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }

}
```

Comment: PERFECT. THANK YOU!!! I see why now. it's actually cause of x and how < 4 is actually 0 1 2 3 4 instead of 4 rows and columns which is 0 1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

0 indexing can play a tricky factor in all kinds of loops. Since your `moveX()` method goes up to `x = 4`, the 0-index count of up to for is 0,1,2,3,4. That is 5 elements. Your matrix is 4x4. You want a count of x=3, giving 0,1,2,3. 4 elements!

You must change your `moveX()` to

```
public void moveX(){
     if (x < 3) 
         x++;
     else { 
         x = 0; 
         y++;
     } 
}
```